# using for-loop with datasnapshot, can't get the value I want

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Get destination_order]

[image: Get picture]

I want to get value in picture col,

```
 DatabaseReference GetDestination_Order = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("results").child(x).child("destination_order");
        GetDestination_Order.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                destination_order.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot Snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    int data = Snapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
                    String im_or = String.valueOf(data);
                    destination_order.add(im_or);
                }
                pass_Destination_order(destination_order);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                throw databaseError.toException();
            }
        });
```

I can get destination_order like 
destination_order: [81, 95, 93, 96, 2]
destination_order: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

```
public void pass_Destination_order(final ArrayList<String> destination_order) {

    for (int n = 0; n < destination_order.size(); n++) {

        String x = destination_order.get(n);

        DatabaseReference myRef1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("---firebaseurl---").getReference("travel").child("0").child("result").child(x).child("picture");
        Log.e("url-x", x);
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = myRef1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                murl="";

                datatest = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Log.e("url", String.valueOf(datatest));
                if (count == 0) {
                    murl += datatest;
                    getImages(murl);`enter code here`

                }
                if(count==destination_order.size()-1){
                    count=0;}
                else
                    count++;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                throw databaseError.toException();
            }
        });
    }
```

I hope to get the picture url ordered by [81, 95, 93, 96, 2]
,but the myurl i get was messed.
why not first myurl belong to 81?  the output/log is below.

[image: logcatpicture]

Comment: Share your complete database structure.

Comment: Please add your database structure and indicate the exact values that you want to get and please responde with @.

Comment: @AlexMamo  i add it ,thanks!

Comment: @Raj i add it ,thanks!

Comment: You are getting destination number but then you are not able to get myurl in that order. Is this your question ?

Comment: @Raj YES absolutely, i can't get the url in that order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all those numbers within `destination_order` node, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("results").child(x).child("destination_order");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            int number = ds.getValue(Integer.class);
            Log.d("TAG", number + ", ");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: add these code below" int numberString im_or = String.valueOf(number);
                        destination_order.add(im_or); " and add pass_Destination_order(destination_order) ?

Comment: Why to do that? Isn't this waht you were looking about, to get those numbers?

Comment: i want to get the picture url

Comment: I cannot se any urls in your picture, only numbers. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: I mean i get destination_order [81,95,93,92,6] and pass into the method to get url,but the first url i get isn't the id=81 was 93's picture url

Comment: Let's stick to one question at a time. Have you got those numbers successfully and printed them in the logat? If yes but starding from there you have another problem, please post a new question for that problem with its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), ok?

Comment: So for another issue, in order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: i can't ask a new question today:<